# Should I enforce the 'one instruction per line' rule?

Tags: php

I am reviewing the following code:

```
$creationDate = $order->getOrderCreationDate();
$dir = Mage::helper('moduleX/order')->getPathOfTheDay($creationDate);
```

The **$creationDate** variable is only used once in the aforementioned code.
I was suggesting to my coworker that it could be simplified  to:

```
$dir = Mage::helper('moduleX/order')->getPathOfTheDay($order->getOrderCreationDate());
```

But he invoked the **one instruction per line** rule, saying that the code was more clean to read and my version of the code could lead to potentially more errors.

What do you think?

Comment: Note that [it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I've put the question on hold because it is framed as a "what is best practice?" question. Furthermore asking us to side with you in a disagreement between coworkers would violate our "did you write this code?" rule, stated in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I am sorry for the phrasing of this question. I was curious if the one instruction per line version was less error-prone, not if "I am right, he is not". The thing is that  the $creationDate variable is only used once so I was wondering if declaring a variable for only one usage in the name of single instruction per line was not a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

Code guidelines are black-and-white rules written for a gray universe. There are times and places where any given rule is either unhelpful or outright harmful. Blind adherence to rules can be frustrating, or even maddening, to someone who can see the shortcomings of a particular rule.

However.

I would always carefully consider whether or not there is a real justification for setting aside a coding guideline. Yes, I'm being paid to exercise my best judgement, but by taking a job, I have also agreed (explicitly or implicitly) to try and follow the rules and guidelines set forth by my employer and the managers under whom I work.

In this case, there is a difference of opinion as to which form the simplest and/or most readable. There is only one rule mentioned - "one instruction per line" and no justification offered for not following that rule. Consequently, under these circumstances, I would be inclined to follow the rule rather than set it aside.

Different circumstances would give a different answer. For example, I work in a language with is hybrid object-oriented/functional and in a functional language, "one instruction per line" would probably not be part of the coding guidelines. Keeping in mind, though, that functional programmers can, and do, get carried away by their own cleverness, leaving behind code that can be very difficult to follow.